# Using Group Based Access Control in Spring security 3.0

Tags: java, spring-security

I am working with CAS integration with my web application with Spring security 3.0 framework.I created a secured page which will be accessed only if the user has ROLE_SUPERVISOR role.

1. When using 
   `"usersByUsernameQuery" value="select username,password,enabled from users where username=?"`
   Everything worked perfect.
2. when using `"groupAuthoritiesByUsernameQuery"`, am able to retrieve the groups of the user logged in. For example. it says the GRANTED Authorities are Administrators,Supervisors which comes from the group_permission table.
   But when i try to access the secured page, it is showing ACCESS DENIED. It seems like the actual roles/permisssions which i assigned to the groups (For e.g ROLE_SUPERVISOR to Supervisors) is not reflected or validated properly.

Am i missing anything? Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself, I am supposed to override this method in my custom jdbcImplentation class

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected List<GrantedAuthority> loadGroupAuthorities(String username) {
    return getJdbcTemplate().query(groupAuthoritiesByUsernameQuery, new String[] {username}, new RowMapper() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
             String roleName = rs.getString("permissionname");
             GrantedAuthorityImpl authority = new GrantedAuthorityImpl(roleName);
             return authority;
        }
    });
}
```